# Introduction to homology of simplitial complex.

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I know the outline of homology theory of simplitial complex and be able to trianglulate some simple figures and compute the homology groups of them, but don't know theoretial details such as what kind of topological spaces we can (or can't) triangulate, and whether the homology groups is always independent from triangulation or there are some spaces that its homology groups depend on triangulation.

Would you tell me a good reference of such fundamental topics of homology theory.

Comment: Maybe Munkres' Algebraic Topology..

Comment: Is this same as Elements of Algebraic Topology?http://webmath2.unito.it/paginepersonali/sergio.console/Dispense/Elements%20of%20Algebraic%20Topology%20-%20James%20R.%20Munkres.pdf

Comment: Yes it is this book. There is also 'elementary differential topology' by Munkres that has a chapter on triangulations of differentiable manifolds.

Comment: 'What kind of topological spaces we can triangulate?' This is a very broad question and I believe there are still open problems about proving whether some space can be triangulated or not. I am not an expert so can't tell you an example. I hope someone will.